# CakePHP - Printing Children of a Post, How To

Tags: cakephp, foreach, parent, children

Below is the debug output from a posts_controller. I currently use the syntax:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?> ... <?php endforeach; ?>
```

to print the posts in the view, however this only yields the outer most posts (ie - the parent posts and no children posts are printed).

QUESTION:

How do I also print all the children posts, directly under each parent post?
Is the solution an embedded foreach loop?

DEBUG:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
                (
                [active] => 1
                [id] => 1
                [parent_id] => 0
                [created] => 2011-08-06 03:54:07
                [modified] => 2011-08-06 03:54:07
                [text] => a
            )

        [Children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [active] => 1
                        [id] => 3
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [created] => 2011-08-08 01:54:24
                        [modified] => 2011-08-08 01:54:24
                        [text] => c
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [active] => 1
                        [id] => 2
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [created] => 2011-08-06 03:54:37
                        [modified] => 2011-08-06 03:54:37
                        [text] => b
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is it an embedded foreach loop the solution?` Uh.. yeah. I don't think there's another way.

> ```
> foreach ($posts as $post):
>     echo $post['Post']['id'];
>     foreach ($post['Children'] as $child_post){}
>   endforeach;
> ```

Comment: Could you show me an example of this please?? I currently use: <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?> ... <?php endforeach; ?> but I cant seem to get at the Children.?

Answer (score 1):

```
$childPosts = Set::extract('/Children', $posts);
```

Comment: Ive already printed the debug in the question but thanks for ur help;)